# Conflict Between "cordova-plugin-firebasex" and "cordova-plugin-advanced-http" Plugins

Tags: java, cordova, ionic-framework, okhttp

After adding **firebasex** to the project the http client of "cordova-plugin-advanced-http" is sending this error to logcat

```
03-17 11:39:23.777 13563 31774 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.appname.name, PID: 13563
03-17 11:39:23.777 13563 31774 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getHttpUrlChecked(Ljava/lang/String;)Lokhttp3/HttpUrl; in class Lokhttp3/internal/Internal; or its super classes (declaration of 'okhttp3.internal.Internal' appears in /data/app/com.appname.name-o8MIMfLOiDEjA11Lh1r2Sg==/base.apk!classes3.dex)
03-17 11:39:23.777 13563 31774 E AndroidRuntime:        at okhttp3.internal.huc.OkHttpURLConnection.buildCall(OkHttpURLConnection.java:373)
03-17 11:39:23.777 13563 31774 E AndroidRuntime:        at okhttp3.internal.huc.OkHttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(OkHttpURLConnection.java:260)
03-17 11:39:23.777 13563 31774 E AndroidRuntime:        at okhttp3.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:229)
03-17 11:39:23.777 13563 31774 E AndroidRuntime:        at okhttp3.internal.huc.OkHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(OkHttpsURLConnection.java:26)
03-17 11:39:23.777 13563 31774 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.silkimen.http.HttpRequest.openOutput(HttpRequest.java:2599)
03-17 11:39:23.777 13563 31774 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.silkimen.http.HttpRequest.send(HttpRequest.java:2904)
03-17 11:39:23.777 13563 31774 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.silkimen.cordovahttp.CordovaHttpBase.sendBody(CordovaHttpBase.java:161)
03-17 11:39:23.777 13563 31774 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.silkimen.cordovahttp.CordovaHttpBase.run(CordovaHttpBase.java:81)
03-17 11:39:23.777 13563 31774 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
03-17 11:39:23.777 13563 31774 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
03-17 11:39:23.777 13563 31774 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
03-17 11:39:25.428  4165  4587 E NativeSemDvfsCpuManager: release:: Start
03-17 11:39:25.428  4165  4587 E NativeSemDvfsCpuManager: release():: mIsAcquired = 1 , mName = CPU  , mTagName : AudioFlinger 
03-17 11:39:25.430  4165  4587 E NativeCustomFrequencyManager: [NativeCFMS] BpCustomFrequencyManager::releaseDVFSLock() 
03-17 11:39:25.430  4165  4587 E NativeSemDvfsCpuManager: release:: End
03-17 11:39:25.469  4693  4733 E KernelCpuUidUserSysTimeReader: Negative user/sys time delta for UID=10253
03-17 11:39:25.469  4693  4733 E KernelCpuUidUserSysTimeReader: Prev times: u=6341651000 s=3599142000 Curr times: u=6341102000 s=3598859000
```

After some debugging and researching I changed **okhttp** to some other versions like 3.4.1 and 3.3.1 also 3.4.0 and others but nothing worked I also tried to use some other versions of **FirebaseX** lib like cli but didn't work

```
ionic info

Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.12.3 (/Users/osama/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.5.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1001.7
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 10.2.0
   @angular/cli                  : 10.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 9.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 13 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res (update available: 0.15.3) : 0.15.2
   native-run                             : 1.3.0

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/osama/Library/Android/sdk)
   ios-sim           : 8.0.2
   NodeJS            : v14.15.4 (/Users/osama/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.14.10
   OS                : macOS Big Sur
   Xcode             : Xcode 12.4 Build version 12D4e
```

**Where maybe the problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `package.json` use this version of OKHTTP

```
"cordova-plugin-advanced-http": {
    "OKHTTP_VERSION": "3.12.1"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix versions of OkHttp, so you should check that you are using a single consistent version. Try upgrading all dependencies to 4.9.1 and seeing if it fixes it.

There is also a BOM mechanism to enforce this in build systems like maven and Gradle https://github.com/square/okhttp#releases

```
    dependencies {
       // define a BOM and its version
       implementation(platform("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-bom:4.9.1"))
       
       // define any required OkHttp artifacts without version
       implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp")
       implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor")
    }
```

Comment: I tried ```com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:4.9.1``` but fails to build

Comment: Ok, sorry to hear that. This should be the fix.  I hope you can sort out whatever is stopping it building.

Comment: Thanks alot, but if we can know the version of OKHTTP used in "firebasex" plugin we can set "http" plugin to use it can you give me a hint how to do so?